# Unable to create observation space array with more than two dimensions

Tags: python, artificial-intelligence, reinforcement-learning, openai-gym, q-learning

We are trying to make a Tetris AI on a raspberry pi which is connected to a board with WS2812b LEDs.
We defined the `action_space` and `observation_space` like this:

```
self.action_space = spaces.Discrete(6)
self.observation_space = spaces.Discrete(width * height * block_number * block_degree * stored_block)
```

We have 6 actions: move left, move right, turn left, turn right, hold block, wait.

Our board has a width of 8 pixels and a height of 16 pixels.

`block_number` is the amount of different blocks, in our case we have 7 different blocks.

`block_degree` is the number of degree when we turn the block right or left (0, 90, 180, 270).

`stored_block` can be used to save a block and use it later. We have 8 different options (block 1-7 or none)

When we use this (`self.observation_space = spaces.Discrete(8*16*7*4*8)`) or any number greater than 2 we get this errror:

```
IndexError: too many indices for array
```

If our `observation_space` 2 or 1 we get this Error:

```
IndexError: index 1 is out of bounds for axis 0 with size 1
```

Does anyone know the problem and how can we find out the right `observation_space`?

Thank you in advance.